I set up minikube's nodePort on MacOS, but I can't access it
I started minikube via minikube start --extra-config=apiserver.service-node-port-range=1-65535
screenshot
Port forwarding was performed as follows.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: dreambank-kings-cross-dev
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 8000 
    nodePort: 50083
  selector:
    app: dreambank-kings-cross 


The settings file is as follows:
enter image description here
When I sent curl from inside the pod, the response came back fine, but
enter image description here
When I checked the minikube internal IP and sent curl, no response came back.
What's the problem?
https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/11193
I tried that way as well, but I want to access it through the minikube IP, not the localhost.
The connection was not made the same even if the "--ports" parameter was used.
I tried various things for two days, but could not solve the problem. Binding to port 30000 and port 60000 also failed..
